# Generate a parser code from a grammar to verify a string

Tags: python, compilation, grammar, parser-generator

I have a grammar, and I want to create a program that take this grammar as a parameter, and generate an output code (in C, Java, Python,...). Therefore, when we compile/run the generated code and pass to it a string/phrase it should check if this string verified with the grammar.

What is the right approach?

**Update:** Adding the grammar example

```
S  -> id ':=' E
E  -> T A
A  -> '+' T A | empty
T  -> F B
B  -> '*' F B | empty
F  -> '(' E ')' | id | number
```

Comment: Please. Show. Your. Code. Thanks.

Comment: What are the constraints on your grammar?  If it is looser than context free, you'll have a bad time.

Comment: I didn't start the coding phase, I'm trying to understand the approach.

Comment: I just added the grammar example.

Comment: Do you know about formal languages, the Chomsky hierarchy of grammars and the special grammar classes used in compiler engineering?  I'm pretty sure this is homework so what is the context?  Compilers?  Formal languages?

Comment: @5gon12eder: Yes, it's a homework, the task is achieved by generating the second program that check if a sentence is verified by the first grammar.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using one of the existing parser generators are available for context-free grammars ?  Options include [Lex & Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/), [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/), [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), etc... depending on your environment.  Or maybe the whole point of the exercise is to have you code a parser yourself ?  In that case, many resources are available ([Matt Might's teaching papers](http://matt.might.net/#teaching) come to mind, among others).

Comment: Th whole point is about implementing the generator/parser from 0.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a trivial task and there isn't even one right solution.  I recommend you review the lecture notes for the class for which you should prepare the assignment and use a technique that was introduced there.

If your grammar is *context free*, you can (after converting it into Chomsky normal form) use the [*Cocke–Younger–Kasami algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) to check whether it can produce a given word.  This algorithm is easy to implement (less than a screen full of Python code) but takes cubic time.  It is mostly used in theoretical computer science.

Actual compilers use faster algorithms but they impose additional requirements on the grammar.  Check out what was introduced in your lecture.  If you want to know how it works in the real world, you can study an existing parser generator like [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).  It is free software so you are free to study its source code.

Good luck!